# How to get columns as zero when there is no data for a specific date in PostgresSql with Springboot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hql, jpql

I'm using PostgreSql. I have a query that gives values for a specific date range. How can i get the columns as zero when there is no data for a specific date. 
Example: the date range is '2018-06-10' to '2018-06-16', and there is no data for the dates 2018-06-15 and 2018-06-16. My existing query returns data for 10th,11th,12th,13th and 14th but not 15th and 16th. How can i get 15th and 16th dates with columns as zeroes.

**here's my query:**

```
 SELECT 40                             AS clientId, 
        0                              AS accountId, 
        0                              AS searchEngineId, 
       'present'                       AS dateType, 
       SUM(em.clicks)                  AS clicks, 
       To_date(em.DATE, 'YYYY-MM-dd')  AS date 
FROM   emailreportstats em 
WHERE  em.clientid = 40 
       AND em.accountid IN ( 13, 14 ) 
       AND em.DATE BETWEEN '2018-06-10' AND '2018-06-16' 
GROUP  BY em.DATE, 
          em.datetype;
```

**Code to execute query:**

```
Query query = em.createQuery(pSqlQuery, EmailReportStats.class);
emailReportStatses = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: You need to do an outer join to a calendar able (or use `generate_series()` to generate one on the fly)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name could you please help me out. I'm unable to do it.

Comment: I've tried this, still no success: select  40 as client_id,stats.clicks as clicks, d.day AS date from (SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2018-06-10', timestamp '2018-06-16', interval '1 day')::date) d(day)LEFT JOIN (select  40 as clientId, sum(em.clicks) as clicks, to_date(em.date, 'YYYY-MM-dd') as date from EmailReportStats em where em.clientId = 40 and em.accountId in (13,14) and em.date between '2018-06-10' and '2018-06-16'  group by em.date, em.dateType)stats ON stats.date = d.day ORDER BY date asc;

Answer (score 0):

You need a `calendar` table. You can generate one on the fly (available only for this query) using `generate_series` function. Then you would outer join your `emailreportstats` to that table, so that you would have all dates covered even if they are not present in your email table.

I've added `coalesce()` wrap to your calculated clicks column and also swapped the input for `date` column.

This is as far as I can go having no table structures and sample data to test it.

```
SELECT  
  40                              AS clientId, 
  0                               AS accountId, 
  0                               AS searchEngineId, 
  'present'                       AS dateType, 
  COALESCE(SUM(em.clicks),0)      AS clicks, 
  calendar.dt                     AS date 
FROM ( 
 SELECT dt::date as dt
 FROM generate_series('2018-06-10', '2018-06-16', '1 day') g(dt) -- input your dates here
) calendar
LEFT JOIN emailreportstats em ON
  calendar.dt = em.date::date
WHERE
  em.clientid = 40 
  AND em.accountid IN ( 13, 14 )
GROUP BY 
  calendar.dt, 
  em.datetype
;
```

Comment: i've tried the solution that you've provided and i'm getting the following exception: 

 ERROR 29696 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 8:6: unexpected token: (

Comment: Can you please first validate if the query is working in Postgresql itself and then later try it in hql? I'm not sure what hql doesn't understand. It's better that you confirm first if it works in psql (connect via command line or any other graphical tool). I'm no expert on hql.

Comment: the query works fine in Postgresql tool, but gives an exception saying columns are missing(columns that we are not querying for) when running through the java code.

Comment: I believe this is due to limiattions in hql. You could probably rewrite the `calendar` part as a view or stored procedure and use it in hql query.